# En javascript; ¿Cómo selecciono una propiedad específica, compartida por los elementos de un array para poder compararla con el valor de una variable?

Tags: array, javascript-objeto

Copio el código para ser mas claro.
Quiero comparar el dato guardado en la variable "user", con el valor de la propiedad "usuario" de cada uno de los elementos del Array,( y no se como seleccionar la propiedad de cada elemento del array )
El resultado lo quiero utilizar para  que al confirmar el usuario y el password recibido por prompt, y si el socio está activo, permita ingresar a la web.

```
let user = prompt("Introduzca su usuario: ");
let pass = prompt("ahora su password: ");

let socios = [
  {
    nombre: "Gustavo",
    apellido: "Castro",
    email: "castrogustavo@gmail.com",
    usuario: "Gustavito",
    password: "soyGus",
    activo: true,
  },
  {
    nombre: "Luis",
    apellido: "Gonzalez",
    email: "luisg@gmail.com",
    usuario: "Luisito",
    password: "soyLuis",
    activo: false,
  }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para seleccionar los elementos tienes que recorrer el array socios, y para seleccionar cualquier propiedad del JSON lo haces así: arreglo[x].propiedad (socios[0].nombre, por ejemplo).

Con el código que indicas te paso este otro, recorre el array y compara las credenciales y si esta inactivo o no

```
for(let r in socios){
   if(user == socios[r].usuario && pass == socios[r].password){
      if(socios[r].activo){
         alert('Eres: ' + socios[r].nombre + ' ' + socios[r].apellido);
      }else{
         alert('Usuario inactivo');
      }
   }
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias José Antonio!  Es muy clara tu respuesta y agradezco mucho el ejemplo extra que me envías.   El (let r in socios )  y el socios [r]; es para que recorra los distintos objetos del array?  sería como cuando usamos la i de index?

Comment: Si, es como si crearas el index con i. Lo que hace la expresión es recorrer el array y va incrementando el r (o el i) en cada iteración.